# Insert Div content in Div dynamically By Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, action

I work with `Javascript` and `Html`. I have two `<div>`

```
<div id="test1">

</div>
```

and

```
<div id="test2">
    Hello World
</div>
```

and I also have button .when click button I want to div `test2` insert into div `test1`

Can anybody help  me?

Comment: Insert `test2` into `test1` or text from `test2` to `test1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the click handler

```
$('#test2').appendTo('#test1')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WDvRb/)

Comment: You can easily use `$('#test2').appendTo('#test1')`.